# How to run a python script in the background from my discord bot

Tags: python, selenium, discord, selenium-chromedriver, discord.py

what I want to do is run my selenium automation script with a discord bot command.(In the users pc not where the bot.py is hosted) I tried to do this in heroku but it ended up consuming too much memory. I want to run the automation script on the users pc when then they use the discord command any help is appreciated.

Comment: May I ask what the selenium script does? I'm not entirely sure this is possible, you will have to use some sort of server for them to run it off of, not to mention they will have to have all the installed packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what I understand, this is not possible because of obvious security reasons. Discord does not allow the bot to use anything other than the provided API which you can find here https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro

Comment: thank you for clarifying this. Much appreciated